# VSCode prettier CSS comment adds line?

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, prettier

Apparently the prettier (1.5.0) on my VSCode (1.23.1) running on Mac (OS 10.13.4) wants to add a line after each comment within an inline css style sheet.  No extra line is added after a comment in the html section, just within the style tags.  Am I missing a prettier setting that controls this?

Or is this related to [the prettier (1.1.0) github issue](https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode/issues/88)  that was closed last year?

Edit: cleaned up the link/text formatting